# Magento separate store by currency but show product in cart with original currency

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, shopping-cart, stores, order-splitting

I have two store one for USD and one for EURO currency, If a user add a product in usd and one add in EURO, then cart page will show price One in USD and one in EURO with two checkout button, one for USD and one for EURO.

That type scenario possible in magento. Below plugin provide me two checkout button for vendor product.

http://webkul.com/blog/magento-marketplace-split-cart/

[image]

I want that type feature without this plugin.

Can we achieve this ? I have a one solution but don't know this the correct  approach or not.

**I create a two store for both currency and don't share cart between store and user add both currency product in cart when user come in cart I will customise cart page and get second store product in cart with original currency then make two button for checkout and linked with particular store.**

That type approach is correct or not.

Please suggest me.